# What type of driver should I write to simulate mouse input as if it was emitted by a real device?

Tags: windows, driver

For a testing purpose, I need to find a way to move the mouse pointer and fire click and scroll events as it does a real user with a real device (in sense of input origin, not data patterns).

Ideally, I want a driver that is able to receive instructions from a user-space app like "move the pointer to (x, y)" or "scroll down for 0.3s". If I understand correctly, this communication can be achieved via IOCtl.

I've read several articles from Microsoft, so I understand there're WDM and WDF, filter drivers and function drivers, Kernel-mode and User-mode, also there's HID whose reports look like something I could use. This field is so huge - I need advice on which path to take to solve my pretty simple problem (basically, move the cursor to a point).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput

Comment: Thank you, I know about SendInput. Say, suppose there are two applications A and B. If A would use SendInput to simulate mouse events within B, is there a chance that B could figure that out? Probably there are some ways to read device status and conclude that it is idle or something like that.

Comment: That is quite hard to do, not entirely impossible.  Intention is certainly to make it look like the input came from a driver.  You've got the basic choice to not get anything done for the next three months or get it done tomorrow.

Comment: I see your point. The problem is I actually need that mentioned quality + SendInput may not work for certain applications (https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simulating-a-keystroke-in-win32-c-or-c-using-sendinput/).

Comment: Hmya, it doesn't work for the kind of people that like to use it to cheat in multiplayer games.  Such games have punkbuster-style countermeasures, easily done by using raw input.  If that is the real problem then just visit the forums where they hang out to find the buster-buster tools they use.

Comment: Well, maybe. The fact is that it's not a universal approach which is required by my stakeholders. What can you say about Virtual Mouse Driver (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54007768/virtual-mouse-kmdf-no-move-of-pointer)? Is that the right direction?

Comment: Not promising, is it?  Getting stuck somewhere in month #2 with an undebuggable problem that no SO user will help with is pretty normal.  Having stakeholders with unrealistic demands is your cross to carry.